# How to generate a DbContext.onmodelcreating approach for Windows Phone 7 SQL Server CE?

Tags: entity-framework, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to conjure an approach to having a code-first like existance within a Windows Phone 7.x app combined with a Portable Class Library that houses the entities.

In that, rather than having my FooClass be decorated with [Table].[Column] attributes I'm keen to approach this from a different angle. I'm keen to have a method or an intercept/override that allows me to define the definition of my SQL Server CE tables before creation and also map them appropriately back to entity classes.

In Entity Framework via .NET 4.5 you can do this via the `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` method but I can't see anything like this for Windows Phone 7?

The closest thing I have found is `CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater()` but that appears to be an approach post database(s) initial creation which won't work if you have `Table<MyEntity>` within your `DataContext` class (for later strong-typing usage elsewhere in your codebase).

Thoughts, Suggestions, Demo code?

Comment: This cannot be done, there is on the CreateDatabase method, and it requires the attributes to be used.